# Disparador copia datos de una columna insertada junto con otros datos independientes

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Estoy aprendiendo `SQL` y estoy ahora centrado en los disparadores.
El disparador que estoy haciendo se ejecuta después de insertar datos en una tabla **"Oficinas"** que cuenta con las columnas: **Oficina (Clave primaria), Región, Dir (Director, clave ajena de otra tabla), Objetivo y Ventas**, en ese orden.
El disparador tiene que ejecutarse después de insertar varias filas de datos en la tabla Oficinas, por lo que ejecuto lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO OFICINAS
    VALUES (1, 'Washington D.C.', 'Este', 108, 200000, 0),
           (2, 'San Francisco', 'Oeste', 106, 275000, 0)
```

El disparador tiene que crear una tabla, si no existe ya, que almacene la fecha y hora a la que se realiza el `Insert`, el tipo de sentencia que es (indicar simplemente `"Insert"`), el número de oficina insertada (oficinas 1 y 2 en este caso) y el usuario que realiza dicho `Insert`, dando como resultado una fila por cada oficina insertada. Para ello hice:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NUEVA_OFICINA
    ON OFICINAS
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM SYS.TABLES
                           WHERE (NAME = 'TControl_Oficinas'))
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE TControl_Oficinas
                    (FECHA_MOD DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     OPERACION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                     OFICINA INT NULL,
                     USUARIO VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)
                END


            INSERT INTO TControl_Oficinas
                VALUES (GETDATE(), 'INSERT', (SELECT OFICINA
                                                  FROM inserted), SUSER_SNAME())
        END
GO
```

El problema lo veo a la hora de mostrar una oficina en cada fila, dado que con el `Insert Into` que tengo codificado se trata de insertar más de un dato en la misma fila por el `Select` que está dentro de `Values`.

Así pues, ¿cómo puedo hacer que el procedimiento cree una fila por cada oficina registrada en la tabla `inserted`, **sin utilizar cursores**?
Gracias de antemano. Puedo proporcionar los dos archivos de las bases de datos si es necesario, pero no sé si proporcionar un link de descarga está permitido, por lo que si no es necesario no lo adjunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es concatenar tu campo llamado OFICINA, lo puedes hacer con el `STUFF` de `SQL`, ademas que ocupas convertir tu campo OFICINA a Varchar  debido a que si lo concatenas como INT, te va a lanzar un error debido a que la coma (,) no es permitida en los enteros.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER NUEVA_OFICINA
    ON OFICINAS
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM SYS.TABLES
                           WHERE (NAME = 'TControl_Oficinas'))
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE TControl_Oficinas
                    (FECHA_MOD DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     OPERACION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                     OFICINA INT NULL,
                     USUARIO VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)
                END


            INSERT INTO 
            TControl_Oficinas(FECHA_MOD,OPERACION,OFICINA,USUARIO)
            SELECT GETDATE(), 'INSERT', OFICINA, SUSER_SNAME() FROM INSERTED
        END
GO
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, necesitas cambiar el tipo de dato de OFICINA a Varchar, debido a que estamos tratando de insertar un Varchar y tu campo es entero.

Comment: Da igual, creo que lo copié mal. Voy a probar de nuevo

Comment: Otro error: "Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar ',' al tipo de datos int."

Comment: Listo, ya deberia de funcionar, falto el convert a varchar al momento de concatenar.

Comment: Vale, ya funciona. El problema es que las oficinas insertadas tienen que mostrarse una en cada fila, es decir, no los números juntos en la misma fila. En el caso que indico en la pregunta, serían dos filas resultantes en TControl_Oficinas, donde la primera almacenaría el 1 correspondiente a la oficina del primer conjunto de valores y la segunda fila almacenaría el 2 del segundo conjunto de valores insertados

Comment: Ha, entendí mal, entonces es mucho mas fácil de lo que pensé, edito mi respuesta(de nuevo) y te cuento.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, creo que eso es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Justo eso. ¡No sabía que era tan simple! Muchas gracias. Marco como respuesta correcta

Comment: Me alegro haberte ayudado, y disculpa la confusión del principio.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes insertar varios registros en tu tabla, valiéndote de la sintaxis `insert`/`select`, de la siguiente manera;

```
CREATE TRIGGER NUEVA_OFICINA
    ON OFICINAS
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                           FROM SYS.TABLES
                           WHERE (NAME = 'TControl_Oficinas'))
                BEGIN
                    CREATE TABLE TControl_Oficinas
                    (FECHA_MOD DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     OPERACION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                     OFICINA INT NULL,
                     USUARIO VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)
                END


            INSERT INTO TControl_Oficinas (Fecha, Operacion, Oficina, Usuario)
            select getdate(), 'INSERT', Inserted.Oficina, suser_sname()
              from Inserted 
        END
GO
```

De esta manera, si un insert tiene 10 oficinas, se crearán 10 nuevos registros en la tabla `TControl_Oficinas`.